# Best tool for DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, dom, serverside-javascript

I'm working on a web scraper which will aggregate data from various websites. I've started using PHP's built in DOM functions but after running into a couple of issues (especially regarding malformed markup and character encoding), I've chosen to ditch PHP. I was thinking of server side Javascript but am open to other suggestions. If I go with Javascript, which interpreter should I use?

Answer (score 2):

Tried [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) yet?

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent [BeautifulSoup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/3.0.8) module for Python which can handle broken markup in most cases. It also allows to use hooks for preprocessing HTML if the page is so malformed that its built-in heuristics doesn't work. I've used BeautifulSoup to write dozens of parsers.

There's also [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) module that is faster and also can parse invalid HTML.

Both modules has Ruby ports.